# Как оптимизировать код php?

Tags: php

model

```
 public function get_customers() {
    $data = array();
    if(is_array($this->config->get('finance_customer_group'))){
        $customer_group_id = implode(",", $this->config->get('finance_customer_group'));
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT *, CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) AS name FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "customer WHERE customer_group_id IN (" . $customer_group_id . ") ORDER BY name ASC");
        $data = $query->rows;
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Передаю в Controller

```
 $customers = $this->model_module_finance->get_customers();
    $this->data['customers'] = array();
    foreach($customers as $customer){
        $costumer_id = $this->model_module_finance->getIdCustomer($customer['customer_id']); Передаю в model


        if($costumer_id['customer_id'] == $customer['customer_id']) {

            $this->data['customers'][] = array(
                'name' => $customer['name'],
                'orders' => $costumer_id['orders'],
                'href' => $this->url->link('module/finance/customer_info', 'customer_id=' . $customer['customer_id'] . '&token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL')
            );
        }else{
            $this->data['customers'][] = array(
                'name' => $customer['name'],
                'orders' => 0,
                'href' => $this->url->link('module/finance/customer_info', 'customer_id=' . $customer['customer_id'] . '&token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL')
            );
        }
    }



public function getIdCustomer($customer_id){ Передаю данные в Controller 

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT oc_order.customer_id, COUNT(oc_order.order_id) as orders FROM oc_order    WHERE oc_order.customer_id = '".$customer_id."' AND oc_order.order_id NOT IN (SELECT order_id FROM oc_finance_order WHERE oc_finance_order.customer_id = '".$customer_id."' ) AND oc_order.order_status_id > 0 AND oc_order.order_status_id !=7 GROUP BY oc_order.firstname ORDER BY oc_order.firstname ASC");
    return $query->row;
}
```

Долго грузится, записей в базе в `order` более 15000 Можно ускорить загрузку?

Comment: $this->db - это коннект PDO? записей 15000, а выбираете единовременно сколько? тоже все 15000? В таблице индексы какие есть? И во второй тоже.

Comment: Это стандартный метод opencart 1.5 я не знаю

Comment: Нет вбирает c первой таб. `customer` только те записи у которых  есть `WHERE customer_group_id IN (" . $customer_group_id . ")` а вторя  `order` выбирает те записи у которых ` WHERE oc_order.customer_id = '".$customer_id."' `

Comment: мне кажется надо оптимизировать не код, а саму БД)

Answer (score 0):

Про подобного рода запросы (когда нужно взять что-то из одной таблицы и исключить записи по условию, завязанному на другую таблицу) почитайте [тут](https://explainextended.com/2010/05/27/left-join-is-null-vs-not-in-vs-not-exists-nullable-columns/).

Предлагаю немного поменять запрос, который Вы используете в функции `getIdCustomer`

Вариант первый:

```
SELECT
    oc_order.customer_id,
    COUNT(oc_order.order_id) AS orders
FROM oc_order
    LEFT JOIN oc_finance_order ocf ON oc_order.order_id = ocf.order_id AND ocf.customer_id = '".$customer_id."'
WHERE
    ISNULL(ocf.order_id) /*любое поле, которое не может быть null из таблицы oc_finance_order*/
    AND oc_order.customer_id = :$customer_id
    AND oc_order.order_status_id > 0 AND oc_order.order_status_id != 7
GROUP BY oc_order.firstname
ORDER BY oc_order.firstname ASC;
```

Вариант второй:

```
SELECT
    oc_order.customer_id,
    COUNT(oc_order.order_id) AS orders
FROM oc_order
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT null FROM oc_finance_order ocf WHERE oc_order.order_id = ocf.order_id AND ocf.customer_id = :$customer_id
    )
    AND oc_order.customer_id = '".$customer_id."'
    AND oc_order.order_status_id > 0 AND oc_order.order_status_id != 7
GROUP BY oc_order.firstname
ORDER BY oc_order.firstname ASC;
```